# Memory isolation (multiple instantiation) of static/global variables

Tags: c#, static, factory, isolation, appdomainsetup

I use a third party class with some static members:

```
class TheirClass{ //from metadata
    static TheirType TheirProp
}
```

I use instances of that class in my code

```
class MyWorkLoad  {
    TheirClass theInstance
}
```

But I require separate context / domains  / whatsoever

```
{//My Program
    var w1 = MyWorkFactory.Create();
        w1.doWorkBasedOnFreshContext()

    var w2 = MyWorkFactory.Create();    
        w2.doWorkBasedOnFreshContext(); //err, dirty context, shared with w1
 }
```

I have tried creating child AppDomains but still getting the same behavior:

```
protected static AppDomain CreatedChildDomain(AppDomain parentDomain)
{
  Evidence evidence = new Evidence(parentDomain.Evidence);
  AppDomainSetup setup = parentDomain.SetupInformation;
  AppDomain.CreateDomain("Lab_"+generationCount, evidence, setup);
}
```

This is the factory method I use to instantiate

```
public static MyWorkLoad Create(string LabConfigPath)
{
    AppDomain subdomain = CreatedChildDomain(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);

    ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap =
        new ExeConfigurationFileMap();

    fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = LabConfigPath;
    var config =
        ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap,
            ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    var conf = config.AppSettings.Settings;
    var nextWork = new MyWorkLoad(subdomain, conf);
    generationCount++;
    return nextWork;
}
```

How may I achieve the desired isolation behavior?

Comment: Please add the code of `MyWorkFactory`.

Comment: AppDomains should provided the necessary isolation (assuming the library isn't doing something with unmanaged code) so how exactly are you using the appdomain that was created?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Thanks, code added. /@MikeZboray: As I am going to explain to you, I should guess that my usage shall be the problem, could you tell more what to do with the created domain? I must have missed something...

Comment: `TheirClass` must be a `MarshalByRefObject` in order the AppDomain magic to work.

Comment: @dymanoid: Thanks. In the case that I cannot change TheirClass (3rd party), does the magic work if I apply it on MyWorkLoad class instead?

Comment: It's unclear what you are doing with the `AppDomain` in your `MyWorkLoad` class. I see you're providing an `AppDomain` instance to that object's .ctor. But as such, each `nextWork` instance is created in the default AppDomain according to your code. Please provide your `MyWorkLoad` code.

Comment: @dymanoid: Thanks a lot. That mentioned uncleanness you emphasized, made it clear for me that I was missing something. So replacing the new instantiation with  subdomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap solved the problem for me. Thanks a lot again for the magic.